# Going from a high-frequency livecard to an immersion (an activity)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to convert the GDK sample compass project (https://developers.google.com/glass/samples/gdk) from using a Livecard base to an immersion / activity base. Some changes I've made include the following:

- CompassRenderer implements SurfaceHolder.Callback rather than DirectRenderingCallback
- CompassView extends SurfaceView rather than View
- Removed CompassService.java
- Created CompassMain.java which extends Activity

  - the onCreate is almost identical
  - the onStarts look like the following code samples

Anyone have any insight?

---

**CompassMain.java**

```
@Override
public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();

    // make view visible
    setContentView(R.layout.compass);

    // create renderer
    CompassRenderer mRenderer = new CompassRenderer(this, mOrientationManager, mLandmarks);

    // get handle to the surface view made visible above
    CompassView surfaceView = (CompassView) findViewById(R.id.compass);

    // magic
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(mRenderer);

    // ensure the screen stays on
    surfaceView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
}
```

---

**CompassService.java**

```
@Override  
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (mLiveCard == null) {
        mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this, LIVE_CARD_ID);
        CompassRenderer mRenderer = new CompassRenderer(this, mOrientationManager, mLandmarks);
        mLiveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true).getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(mRenderer);

        // Display specific card scroll view based on orientation
        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, CompassMenuActivity.class);
        menuIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, menuIntent, 0));

        mLiveCard.attach(this);
        mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);
    } else {
        mLiveCard.navigate();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. Here are the additional changes I made:

- Changed the onStart() within my main activity while adding an argument to the CompassRenderer constructor
- Changed the CompassRenderer constructor's body

---

**CompassMain.java**

```
@Override  
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    // show the view and create the 
    setContentView(R.layout.compass);

    CompassView compassView = (CompassView) findViewById(R.id.compass);

    CompassRenderer mRenderer = new CompassRenderer(this, mOrientationManager, mLandmarks, compassView);

    compassView.setWillNotDraw(false);

    compassView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    compassView.getHolder().addCallback(mRenderer);
}
```

---

**CompassRenderer.java**

```
public CompassRenderer(Context context, OrientationManager orientationManager, Landmarks landmarks, CompassView compassView) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mLayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.compass, null);
        mCompassView = compassView;
        mOrientationManager = orientationManager;
        mLandmarks = landmarks;
        mCompassView.setOrientationManager(mOrientationManager);
    }
```

Comment: I get an error on the compassView.getHolder() line:
The method getHolder() is undefined for the type CompassView?

Comment: Did you change the CompassView class from a View to a SurfaceView?

Comment: I was able to get it working, (I don't quite remember how).  Thanks for this post it was a big help!